# How to know DLT pipeline run status (failed, completed) using REST API?

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

Is there a way to find out DLT pipeline run status like if pipeline failed or succeeded ?

I was looking into the API https://docs.databricks.com/workflows/delta-live-tables/delta-live-tables-api-guide.html#pipelinestateinfo

State in below doesn't have failed status
[image]

I'm looking to have report which shows pipeline run info, expectation info ( I was able to get this from event log ) .

Answer (score 2):

[UpdateStateInfo](https://docs.databricks.com/delta-live-tables/api-guide.html#update-state-info) seems what you're after, doesn't it?

> The current state of a pipeline update.

where `state` is described as follows:

> The state of the update. One of QUEUED, CREATED, WAITING_FOR_RESOURCES, INITIALIZING, RESETTING, SETTING_UP_TABLES, RUNNING, STOPPING, COMPLETED, FAILED, or CANCELED.

---

I use [Delta Live Tables CLI](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/cli/dlt-cli.html) (aka `databricks pipelines`) to interact with Delta Live Tables API. Use `--debug` flag to find out what it does under the covers.

```
$ databricks pipelines get --pipeline-id 960da65b-c9df-4cb9-9456-1005ffe103a9 | jq '.latest_updates'
[
  {
    "update_id": "967094d6-6751-4d4c-94ea-40950a9e7f8e",
    "state": "FAILED",
    "creation_time": "2023-03-16T17:43:54.278Z"
  },
  {
    "update_id": "2187cb69-8161-4013-816f-1be6a1a6728b",
    "state": "COMPLETED",
    "creation_time": "2023-03-10T15:02:08.598Z"
  },
  {
    "update_id": "a8893445-aedd-4af8-a42b-80e64b43ef7a",
    "state": "COMPLETED",
    "creation_time": "2023-03-10T11:38:54.316Z"
  },
  {
    "update_id": "509264a4-5589-4d40-a940-5859fe37142c",
    "state": "COMPLETED",
    "creation_time": "2023-03-10T10:43:26.921Z"
  },
  {
    "update_id": "262e4c01-b563-4d8a-913a-a4c25e927682",
    "state": "COMPLETED",
    "creation_time": "2023-03-09T16:54:49.801Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: does it also maintains history ? sorry I did not try yet. I'm looking to get pipeline run status for a given pipeline so far

Comment: History? I don't think I understand.